# Cordova Android - can't open camera - READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, cordova, permissions

I am trying to open a camera on my Cordova app since moving it over to Android Studio and now it has stopped working.

I get no popup of permissions, or anything on the user side to show me otherwise.

I get the following error in the Android Monitor

```
com.ontrac.nutshellmobile E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=8324, uid=10182 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:616)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:487)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:216)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

My manifest has the following permissions

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I am running API 26 for the compile SDK version on the project structure.

My build gradle files contain the SDK versions of

```
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 25
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
```

I have tried moving the permissions over to the Cordova Android manifest but no luck. I cant seem to figure out what is causing the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can give more information if needed.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 2):

In order to open camera, you have to install **cordova-plugin-android-permissions**.

you have to ask for 2 permissions: **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **CAMERA**, and open the camera in the callback function of the 2 functions.

example of the js code:

```
function takePicture() {
  var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
  permissions.requestPermission(permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    function (status) {

      if (!status.hasPermission)
       error();
      else
       permissions.requestPermission(permissions.CAMERA, success.bind(this),
      error);

      function error() {
        console.warn('CAMERA permission is not turned on');
      }
    }
    , error);

    function error() {
      console.warn('READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not turned on');
    }

    function success(status) {
      if (!status.hasPermission)
       error();
      else
       openCamera();
    }
  }

  function openCamera() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
      quality: 25,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {

      var src = "data:image/png;base64," + imageData;
      console.log(src);
      alert('got picture!!!');
    }

    function onFail(message) {
      alert('error ' + message);
    }
  }

  takePicture();
```